# Com CSS é possível colocar 2 cores em 1 letra? Ou metade do texto com uma cor diferente?

Tags: css, css3, font

Gostaria de saber se com CSS tem como deixar apenas metade de uma letra, ou metade de uma palavra, com outra cor e a outra metade com outra?

**Seria possível chegar nesse resultado da imagem abaixo só com CSS?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o modelo base que tenho no momento.

```css
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 6rem;
    color: red;
    margin:.15em;
}
```

```html
<h1>A</h1>
<h1>ABC</h1>
```

Comment: Perdi. Vou deixar alguém responder

Comment: @WallaceMaxters se tiver algo com CSS seria interessante!

Comment: Eu tentei definir o `color: transparent` e colocar dois valores em `text-shadow`. Você pode brincar com isso se quiser.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters acho que com linear-gradiente vc teria um resultado melhor hein...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

O mais próximo que consegui foi usando `background-clip: text`e `text-fill-color: transparent`.

Veja:

```css
.two-colors{
   font-size: 160px;
   background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, red 0);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Arial;
  
}
```

```html
<span class="two-colors">A</span>
<span class="two-colors">B</span>
<span class="two-colors">ABC</span>
```

Elaborei o CSS parecido com o dessa [resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009470/two-colors-in-text-in-css), porém eu mudei a direção do gradiente, para ficar meio a meio verticalmente as cores e preferi aplicar o estilo letra por letra.

No caso, para as letras ficarem "na mesma linha", é necessário que o elemento que recebe o estilo tenha definido o `display` com o valor `inline-block` ou `inline`.

Answer (score 17):

Você pode usar um SVG com texto dentro dele.

```html
<svg width="200" height="80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="bicolored">
            <stop offset="33%" stop-color="red"/>
            <stop offset="33%" stop-color="blue"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="tricolored">
            <stop offset="33%" stop-color="red"/>
            <stop offset="33%" stop-color="green"/>
            <stop offset="66%" stop-color="green"/>
            <stop offset="66%" stop-color="blue"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="smooth">
            <stop offset="33%" stop-color="red"/>
            <stop offset="66%" stop-color="blue"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <text x="0" y="20" fill="url(#bicolored)">Some bicolored Text</text>
    <text x="0" y="40" fill="url(#tricolored)">Some tricolored Text</text>
    <text x="0" y="60" fill="url(#smooth)">Some smooth gradient Text</text>
</svg>
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34293307/1452488

Answer (score 13):

Usando apenas CSS da pra fazer dessa forma

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red 10%, blue 0%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>
The BLA BLA
</h1>
```

Comment: Incrível. Top demais .

Answer (score 6):

Mais um...

```css
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 6rem;
    margin: .15em;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,blue 50%, red 50%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1>A</h1>

<h1>ABC</h1>
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar uma explicação. Esse `linear-gradient` sempre me confunde e não entendi porque o seu ficou "sem opacidade" de uma cor para outra. Ficou a cor sólida. É por causa do `left`? (eu usei `to left`, tem alguma diferença?

Answer (score 6):

Também é possível utilizando um *pseudo-elemento* `::after` com o `content:"A"` igual ao do texto `<h1>A</h1>`, porém "cortado" em 50% da largura.

```css
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 6rem;
    color: red;
    margin:.15em;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
h1::after {
    content: attr(data-texto);
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: blue;
    text-transform: uppercase;
pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-texto="a">A</h1>
<h1 data-texto="ABC">ABC</h1>
```

Comment: É uma alternativa às anteriores. Mas no Firefox, pelo menos, atrapalha um pouco a seleção do texto.

Comment: @fernandosavio legal a observação, vc tem razão, selecionando na mão fica meio estranho, mas dando dois cliques na palavra é de boa, de qualquer forma é um pondo a se levar em consideração ao escolher o método!

Comment: Era pra ter escrito que era uma **boa** alternativa aos anteriores...
Mas de qualquer maneira, fica como observação caso alguém esbarre aqui.

Comment: Pode fazer como no exemplo daquela minha outra resposta da pergunta do dia, usando `::after` e `::before`. Dai não precisa repetir o texto na hora de selecionar não acontece esse efeito (porque não seleciona nada)

Comment: É verdade, inclusive editei e coloquei `pointer-events: none;  user-select: none;` no `::avter` valeu a dica!